# admob native express ads not show

Tags: android, admob

i try everything in stackoverflow but ads not show. banner and other working but native not working please help me.

```
inal NativeExpressAdView mAdView2 = (NativeExpressAdView) findViewById(R.id.adView2);
    // Set its video options.
    mAdView2.setVideoOptions(new VideoOptions.Builder()
            .setStartMuted(true)
            .build());

    // The VideoController can be used to get lifecycle events and info about an ad's video
    // asset. One will always be returned by getVideoController, even if the ad has no video
    // asset.
    mVideoController = mAdView2.getVideoController();
    mVideoController.setVideoLifecycleCallbacks(new VideoController.VideoLifecycleCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVideoEnd() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Video playback is finished.");
            super.onVideoEnd();
        }
    });

    // Set an AdListener for the AdView, so the Activity can take action when an ad has finished
    // loading.
    mAdView2.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mAdView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (mVideoController.hasVideoContent()) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Received an ad that contains a video asset.");
            } else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Received an ad that does not contain a video asset.");
            }
        }
    });

    mAdView2.loadAd(adRequest);
```

this activity code

this is xml code . please help me.

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
    android:id="@+id/adView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-000000"
    ads:adSize="300x150"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
```

Logcat report
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wait a little. Your ad id is newly created so it will take some time to fetch ads from google servers.

It also happened to me that error **"fail to load ad 0"** but there is no problem just wait for sometimes like an hour or 2 or even 5 hours just wait you will get the ads.